# Rendering HTML from JSON with mustache

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mustache, lighthouse

I have a Node.JS file that outputs page load analysis test results. I have stored the results in a file `results.json`, with `JSON.stringify()`.

```
launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/', flags, perfConfig).then(results => {
    fs.appendFile('results.json', JSON.stringify(results), (err) => {
        if(err){ throw err; }
        console.log('Data was appended to file!');
        var myObj = results.json; //problematic
        var JSON_to_HTML = mustache.render('This test was generated at this time: {{generatedTime}}.', myObj); //problematic
    });
});
```

Now I want to display the results in the browser, so I want to translate the JSON into HTML. I want to use mustache for this, but these lines aren't working for me:

```
var myObj = results.json;
var JSON_to_HTML = mustache.render('Test was generated at this time: {{generatedTime}}.', myObj);
```

I get the error "results isn't defined", the JSON file can't be read by mustache like this. I can't initialize "myObj" with the raw JSON, because it's about a million lines (and I need to later run tests for a whole bunch of pages, so I can't hardcode that right now).

I'm not sure how to translate this JSON file I have now into HTML. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm a beginner to Node and Mustache, any tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: `launchChromeAndRunLighthouse` must be returning undefined. You verify mustache is working by rendering some static data `console.log(mustache.render('{{foo}}', {foo: 'bar'}))` should log `bar`.

Comment: When I try `console.log(mustache.render('{{foo}}', {foo: 'bar'}))` in a new file I get an error message that mustache is not defined. I installed it, initially globally but then just locally. Is there anything else I would have to do to use mustache? EDIT: I can open the JSON file and see the results of the tests, it's not undefined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of googling led me to my own answer.

To read the JSON file of the test results and make an HTML page out of it, I had to create a package.json file for this Node module (ran `npm init`). After I created the file, I opened it in sublime and edited the `scripts` so a CLI command 'build' would take the .json file, take a .mustache file with the stuff I wanted to display from the .json file, and stick those in a .html file.

`"scripts": {
    "build": "mustache results.json basicTemplate.mustache > theDisplay.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },`

results.json is where I stringified into, from the question. basicTemplate.mustache is for now

`{{generatedtime}} {{initialurl}}`

and theDisplay.html is just a basic html template (like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)).

Now when I run `node <name of node module>`, the results file is generated. Then I run `npm run build`, and this script I just created in the package.json is run. That modifies theDisplay.html. You should now be able to double-click theDisplay.html in Finder, and a browser opens up with the time the tests were generated, as well as the url of the page tested.